# FTP Client with EJB3 in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have a Stateless Session Bean (in JBOSS container) that does download a file from remote FTP server using org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient. It then temporarily stores the file in local System tmp directory (java.io.tmpdir) and processes the content mainly by adding it into a Database using Hibernate.

Now EJB Specifications do tell me not to use java.io.File, java.io.FileInputStream and so on. Basically not to do any "direct" filesystem access at all.

Now how am I supposed to do my task ? Does anyone have a hint, link, example ?

Thank you in advance

mostart

Comment: Maybe you are supposed to contact the other server through its own application/http server to get the data? Just saying.

Comment: The remote Server is a third party Server which is not under my control. It only allows ftp client access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not access the local file system to store any data which you would use later in your application. If your application resides on a cluster then the locally stored files won't be accessible from each cluster member, that's why the documentation doesn't recommend to use java.io at all. That's the easiest way to avoid such inconsistency.

However, if you need to work with temporary files only, which you can delete before the end of your bean's life-cycle, then you can use java.io without any worry. The point is that, don't store locally anything which you want access from your app later.

Answer (score 0):

How about having your own local/remote ftp server for storing the incoming files? Then you just use the FTPClient and not access file system directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out I could refactor the modul to just operate on the download Stream directly rather than temporarily saving it in the file system.

thanks for your hints..